# Dynamic generation of parallel stages in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, parallel-processing, stage

I am trying to generate dynamic parallel stages in jenkins. I have reach a point in which it work but they are not dynamic:

```
pipeline{
  agent {
    label "node-18"
  }
  parameters{
    ...
  }
  environment{
    ...
  }
  stages{
    stage('whatever previos stage'){
      script{
        .... whatever previos things here (it doesnt matter)
      }
    }
  }

  stage('Run test in parallel'){
    parallel{
      stage('test 0'){
        agent{
          label "node-18"
        }
        steps{
          script{
            runTest('0')
          }
        }
        post{
          always{
            publishrepo('0') //this method use the html publisher
          }
        }
      }
      stage('test 1'){
        agent{
          label "node-18"
        }
        steps{
          script{
            runTest('1')
          }
        }
        post{
          always{
            publishrepo('1') //this method use the html publisher
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This works perfect and also publish the HTML reports in the jenkins page so, so far so good, the problem is that there are not always two stages, there is a method  that calculate the max numbers of paralelization and according to this numbers I have to create 0 to N stages.

I tried this checking some post on the internet and so on:

```
def maxParallelSteps = [:]
pipeline{
  agent {
    label "node-18"
  }
  parameters{
    ...
  }
  environment{
    ...
  }
  stages{
    stage('whatever previos stage'){
      script{
        .... whatever previos things here (it doesnt matter)
      }
    }
  }

  stage('Check number of stages and create them'){
    steps{
      script {
        def max = checkMaxParallel()
        for(int i = 0 ; i< max ; i++){
           maxParallelSteps.put("test ${i}", generateStage(i)
        }
      }
    }
  }

  stage('Run test in parallel'){
    steps{
      script{
        parallel maxParallelSteps 
      }
    }
  }
}

def generateStage(slot){
  return {
    stage('test ' + slot){
      agent{
        label 'node-18'
      }
      steps{
        script{
          runTest('1')
        }
      }
      post{
        always{
          publishrepo('1') //this method use the html publisher
        }
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

In this case I am getting the following error:

[image]

take into account that I didnt copy and paste but the idea is that test 0 and so on are P0_test and so on.

I also tried to move the for loop just in one stage and a lot of crazy things. I dont know what else to test and where to find a proper example of doc about how to dynamically do that.
The point is that the first code I showed you works perfectly the only point will be to be able to according to just a number create X number of stages.

I hope I have explain properly my issue and thanks in advance to all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating real dynamic parallel steps in declarative pipeline is indeed not possible, so you used the only available way which is to use the [parallel](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-cps/#parallel-execute-in-parallel) keyword which is taken from the scripted pipeline syntax (thus requires the `script` context).
This means that the execution code that is passed to the parallel step should be also written in scripted syntax, in your case the `generateStage` function is generating decelerative syntax code and therefore the errors.

To solve it you can modify your function to scripted syntax:

```groovy
def generateStage(slot) {
  return {
    stage("test ${slot}") {
       node('node-18') {
          try {
             runTest('1')
          }
          finally {
              publishrepo('1') //this method use the html publisher
          }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Btw you don't have to separate into a function and can run it inside the stage:

```groovy
pipeline{
  agent {
    label "node-18"
  }
  parameters{
    ...
  }
  environment{
    ...
  }
  stages{
    stage('whatever previos stage'){
      script{
        .... whatever previos things here (it doesnt matter)
      }
    }
  }

  stage('Create and run stages'){
    steps{
      script {
        def parallelSteps = (1..checkMaxParallel()).collectEntries {
          ["test ${i}" : {
              stage("test ${slot}") {
                  node('node-18') {
                     try {
                        runTest('1')
                     }
                     finally {
                        publishrepo('1') //this method use the html publisher
                     }
                 }
              }
           }]
        parallel parallelSteps 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for such info! it worked! I could find any doc actually for doing things like that and since it was possible in declarative mode with parallel to do this thing I didnt know it was not possible to continue doing that in declarative mode with stages! Thanks a lot again